# VS Code : when opening it, shows hamburger menu by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code v1.82.1. When I click the VS Code icon in my Windows app bar holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, it opens in a new window.

The problem is that the window has a 1024px width the main menu (File, Edit, Selection, ...) is hidden and the hamburger menu is displayed.

So I have to click on the hamburger, then File, ... so there is an extra click in the hamburger.

Is it possible to tell Windows or VS Code to open the new window in a specific width like 1100px or even maximized?

Comment: Maybe look at win11 powertools

Comment: if you already have another VS Code window open when you open the new one, see the `window.newWindowDimensions` setting. Otherwise, I'm pretty sure this question is off-topic (about using windows rather than VS Code).